# App getting crashed when moving to a new view from the table view in android

Tags: android

Im a newbie in android development and thats why im asking you experts such a simple problem

I created a table view and it is working fine.

I tried to move to a new view when clicking on the first cell and for that i created a new file Newview.java.

But when clicking on the first cell app is crashing and showing the message "Unfortunately HelloTableLayout has stopped".

Can anyone please help me with this.

```
HelloTableLayoutActivity.java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloTableLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView name =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent nameActivity =new Intent();
        nameActivity .setClass(getApplicationContext(), Newview.class);
        startActivity(nameActivity);

    }
        });
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/initial"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/hometown"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/state"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>      
</TableLayout>
```

Newview.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Newview extends Activity
{
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foo);
    }
}
```

HelloTableLayout Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sweans.tb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".HelloTableLayoutActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".NewviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

foo.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me where im going wrong in my code and why the app is crashing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the LogCat trace in here... the text in Red color should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the following code .

```
 Intent nameActivity =new Intent();
 nameActivity .setClass(getApplicationContext(), Newview.class);
 startActivity(nameActivity);
```

with the below code.

```
Intent nameActivity =new Intent(HelloTableLayoutActivity.this,Newview.class);
 startActivity(nameActivity);
```

and define your Newview class in android manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".Newview" > </activity>
```

Because as you call Newview from your main class and you declare NewviewActvity class in android manifest file , so when you click on textview at that time android finds the Newview class in android manifest file, because it not present in that manifest file your application goest to crash.

Comment: if suppose i want to move to a new view when click, on second and third rows also how can i do that.Can you please tell me

Comment: you can call the new view like the same you do in above example.